# Rails: How can i save the outcome of a for loop into database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm new in rails and I could need some help. Been stuck in this for few days. I've searched the solution but don't get it still. The problem is I want to save the outcome of the for loop into database (postgreSQL).

```
    <% @amount = (params[:h].to_d * params[:k].to_d) %> 
    <% @percent = (params[:h].to_d * params[:k].to_d) / params[:p].to_d %>
<% for i in 0..params[:a].to_i do %>  
    <% @newAmount = ((@amount/(@percent)) + @amount) %>  
    <%= "#{i}" + " - #{@amount}" %><br />
    <% @amount=@newAmount %>
<% end %>
```

Very good would be if I could save the form data also, I found out that form_tag ain't very good to save data, but I don't really know how to do this with form_for.

```
<%= form_tag ('/calc') do  %> 
  A_n: <%= text_field_tag :a_n %><br />
  H: <%= text_field_tag :h %><br />
  K: <%= text_field_tag :k %><br />
  P: <%= text_field_tag :p %><br />
  A: <%= text_field_tag :a %><br />
  <%= submit_tag 'Calc' %>
<% end %>
```

I am sorry if this is basic or really simple (which I'm sure it is) but I hope I can find some help how to do this properly.

Model:

```
class Calculation < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :a, :a_n, :h, :k, :p
end
```

Table:

```
  create_table "calculation", :force => true do |t|

    t.string   "a_n"

    t.decimal  "h"

    t.decimal  "k"

    t.decimal  "p"

    t.integer  "a"

    t.datetime "created_at",  :null => false

    t.datetime "updated_at",  :null => false

  end
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly you want to save. and what is the table/model structure. Provide some code for model.

Comment: edited the post. I want to save the outcome of for loop (years and numbers for each year) but if its possible id like to save the data I enter to form also so I can see where the outcome comes.

Comment: ok.. I can see all the parameters from the `form` except **y**, instead I see another column named **a** in the table. Is it a typo and if its not then what do you want to store in that column? And where will the for loop's data will be stored?

Comment: No problem. though still some more information needed. You are using the for loop in a **view**, is it the same view the form is in. And from where are you getting `params[:a]` in view. And 1 more thing the for loop is adding the value in `@amount`. Do you want to save the final value of `@amount` if yes, then where I mean in which column of your table.?

Comment: it was typo, sorry. I want for loop's data also to store in db, like form's, but for for loop's data I must make new database for the i and amount?

First of all, I am so thankful for you for helping me on this. It is the same view where the form is in. params[:a] is the parameter that I enter in. I want to save all the values for amount's (like I enter the params[:a] for the value of "5", then I get 0 - amount, 1 - amount...).

Comment: I don't think thats a good idea, you can save the values of `@percent, params[:a]` and the value of `@amount` before the for loop. And whenever you need to display, you can use the same loop and display accordingly. I am not sure from where you are getting `@percent, @amount` etc, if they are from database or can be generated using some logic then you should not save them as well.

Comment: Sorri I don't know why I left them out. I edited the post again, they are before for loop in view. I think now, that if I save the data of the form only, then using the loop I can display them again...but then how to save form_tag, I know how to save form_for...

Comment: You are quite close now. why don't you use form_for? Is there any specific reason?

Comment: You can calculate all in your Calculation model. For example use callback `before_save :calculate` `def calculate; amount = (h * k) / p; end;` But what's the purpose of the calculations?

Comment: @itsnikolay the program needs to calculate the amount, and this amount changes every year by a certain percent. I didn't know I can do calculations in Model, or I thought it's not a good way doing it. I tried to do the calculations in controller, but it gave me "no method error to_d" for getting parameter "params[:p].to_d" for example. Thats why the calculations are in view.

Comment: @SybmariteManoj I used form_for for making blogs and stuff, but didn't find a way to make the calculator like this. I give it a try again.

Comment: `form_for` is just a method to generate the `form tag` in html with the given object. Actually it generate the `<form>` html tag and get the required details from the object for which it was used. :)

Comment: @SybariteManoj I kinda changed everything, and now when I want to do the for loop, it gives me "undefined method `to_d' for nil:NilClass". The data I enter to the form_for is saved. I hope to find a way to pass this error...

Comment: Its getting lengthy discussion here.. come on join me @ http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24054/discussion-between-manoj-and-kaits

Comment: Oh sorry.. I didn't see that.. Anyways My question was, as you're using `params` in the view to calculate. but from where are you getting these values. What I understood from your code is the values has to be submitted by the form and the form has not yet submitted.

Comment: @SybariteManoj I can't say how thankful I am to you. I made it with form_for and made everything differently, now it looks like actual site with delete, edit, show and lots of actions thanks to this. Saving works. I post new view that changed everything. Thank you again for helping and directing me!

Comment: You are welcome :) If the problem got solved, then please add the updated code or your solution as an answer here and accept it :) It might help other visitors.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is what my form looks like, with form_for its really easy to make the validations so why not make them?

```
<%= form_for @calculation do |f| %>
  <% if @calculation.errors.any? %>
    <h2>Errors:</h2>
    <ul>
      <% @calculation.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
  A n: <%= f.text_field :a_n %><br />
  H: <%= f.text_field :h %><br />
  K: <%= f.text_field :k %><br />
  P: <%= f.text_field :p %><br />
  A: <%= f.text_field :a %><br />
  <%= f.submit 'CALC' %>
<% end %>
```

And the show view is:

```
<p>A n: <%= @calculation.a_n %></p>
<p>H: <%= @calculation.h %></p>
<p>K: <%= @calculation.k %></p>
<p>P: <%= @calculation.p %></p>
<p>A: <%= @calculation.a %></p>
<small>T: <%= @calculation.created_at %></small>
 <br />
    <%= @calculation.a_n %> <br />
    <% @amount = (@calculation.h * @calculation.k) %> 
    <% @percent = (@calculation.h * @calculation.k) / @calculation.p %> 
  <% for i in 0..@calculation.a do %> 
    <% @newAmount = ((@amount/(@percent)) + @amount) %>
    <%= "#{i}" + " - #{@amount}" %><br />
    <% @amount=@newAmount %>
  <% end %>
```

This works perfectly! Thank you for your attention and for help!

Comment: Logic should not be in views, move them to a helper or model methods instead.